# Social login disabled buttons styling web

Tags: javascript, css, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

For Facebook and Google login (web), are there disabled styled versions of their buttons that can be used?

My use case is I want to show a slightly greyed out version of both buttons if there are adblocking or third party cookie issues. This shows a user that they are options, but something went wrong, and they should contact me.

In Googles brand guidelines, the linked assets folder has disabled buttons in the Sketch file, but no mention anywhere else.

I believe Facebook only allows the text and sizing to be changed on their Login buttons.

Any more information out there?

Comment: It may be worth trying to add the [`disabled` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) onto the button. They may have a custom style for elements with the attribute.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson no dice :( using the js sdk to init buttons